# Calculate number of days between two days on certain condition

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to calculate number of days between subscription days($dat) and duration($duration) which could be 1 month or 3 month or 6 month. If duration is 1 month I want to add 30 days to it from the date of subscription and decrease the count each day until it becomes 0 and display it in table. I don't know how to deacrease the count and create a conndition.

**c_details.php**

```
<?php while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>       
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php
        $time=new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('$dat')));
        $time1=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));;
        $interval=date_diff($time1, $time);
        echo $interval->format('%a days');
        </td>
    </tr>
?>
```

**sub_details.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
session_start();
/* 
$email = $_POST['email']; */
$newspaper = $_POST['paper'];      // Paper
$duration = $_POST['duration'];     // Duration
$price = $_POST['price_hidden']; // total
$dat = date('Y-m-d');            //date of subscription
$name = $_SESSION['login_user'];
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a variable for the date/time the subscription started?

Comment: Yes it is in sub_details.php. $dat is date of subscription.

Comment: Ok I see. It seems the current duration would be the starting timestamp subtracted from today's timestamp. And the time left would be current duration subtracted from the total duration.

Comment: So you want to let the user input the duration and start a subscription from the date till the duration (1/3/6 months) right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This looks like a good example to learn test-driven development from. Model the simplest cases in test cases, write the proper code, and then go on to more difficult cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Updated as per your latest code

```
$time  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')); // Todays date
$time1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')); // Todays date
$time1->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // Adds 1 month to $time1
$interval = date_diff($time1, $time); // The interval between $time1 and $time
echo $interval->format('%a days'); // Outputs 29 days
```

> A workaround for the real problem:

1. Calculate and save a subscription end date on the database.
2. Then show the number of days left to the subscription end date

To calculate the subscription end date based on the `duration`.

```
$dateNow = new DateTime();// today's date
// P1M will add one month. You can change the interval based on the duration selected
$subscriptionEndDate = $dateNow->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
echo $subscriptionEndDate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');


// You can even use 
$subscriptionEndDate = $dateNow->modify("+ 60 days");
// Check out PHP documentation for more cool ways to do this
```

> Read more about PHP DateTime class [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Save the subscription end date in the `subscription_end_date` column in your database table.

Now use an appropriate method (based on how you save the dates in the DB tables) to get the difference between the current date and subscription end date.

For example:

> Using MySQL [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURDATE(), '2020-02-29');
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I need to display it in table format. I tried to display but it is not showing any values. Here is my code                                                                     
            <?php
            
            if(!empty($_SESSION['s_date']) && !empty($_SESSION['e_date'])){
            $date1=date_create();
            $interval=date_diff($edate,$date1)->format("%a days");
             ?>
             <td><?php echo $rows['$interval$']; ?></td>
             <?php } ?>

Comment: a few questions: Is the SESSION Variables set correct? What is $edate? What do you meant by this statement? <?php echo $rows['$interval$']; ?>

Comment: Session variables are set correctly. $e_date is subscription end date. The statement should display the remaining days in table but it is not displaying any values.